# How to deal with 61W power adapter not working issue

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, battery, charging, charger

I have apple MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2020, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports).

The power adapter is not working , there is no issue with

- Charging pin
- Charging cable

[image]

[image]

- Can I use 140W USB-C Power adapter with this laptop ?
- Can I use Universal travel adapter which has USB-C slot ? [ The adapter doesn't mention any watts ]
- Can I use fast charging USB-C plug ? [ The plug doesn't mention any watts in it ]
- Can I use normal USB-C plug ? [ This too doesn't mention any watts in it ]

As of now I can't afford to buy a new 61W power adapter but I'm not sure whether the power adapter would kill SMPS system of laptop etc .. ?

Someone share their insights please

FYI:
This adapter converts AC to DC and gives steady 61W power supply to the laptop.

But if we use adapter that gives higher or lower watts DC then what happens , if that doesn't damage then I think it's good enough to use this as temporary solution If I am not wrong

Update:

Mac book draws - 20.3 Voltage , 3 Amperage and 61 Watts

Power adapter outputs - 5 voltage , 2 to 6 Amperage and 30 watts

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your questions boil down to any USB C power source will work. The lowest wattage ones will only trickle charge (think 18w) but they will charge the device slowly. The mid wattage units (30 to 60w) take longer to charge so that’s the only downside of going too small.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201700

Try to get something close to the original if you use a lot of battery capacity and can’t take break to allow a slow charge to catch you up during the day. You might also find the 30w model fine for light use.

> If your Mac uses USB-C to charge, you can charge your Mac laptop with any USB-C power adapter or display. You can safely use a power adapter or display with higher or lower wattage than the adapter included with your Mac.

Even though your model doesn’t fast charge, if you want quickest charges, look for the 67 w or higher models per the MacBook Air 2022 list below:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212755

Comment: Just one question , will it not spoil the battery in anyways ?

Comment: Hi @King - what is "spoiling the battery"? are you worried about charging too fast or too slow or some other item?

Comment: I mean under voltage, under amperage or under watts can do any damage to laptop battery or laptop ?

Comment: There is no such thing with USB C power delivery. There are controller chips that don't even engage the charge circuitry until a handshake is established and safety guidelines are met. The voltage is known and the system will reject an out of tolerance charger or defective cable in almost all circumstances. (Of course things can really break and no system can be perfect as things are small and not 10x redundant). The only concern is if you use too much energy, choosing a lover wattage charger means you run out of battery and can't use the device until it charges at a slower rate.